# Split at every i-th and j-th char

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to split a string at every i-th and j-th character, where i and j can change according to input parameters. If for example i have an input

```
String s = "1234567890abcdef";
int i = 2;
int j = 3;
```

I want my output to be an array of:

```
[12, 345, 67, 890, ab, cde, f]
```

I found a compact regex to split at every n-th char. Example for n = 3 using `"(?<=\\G...)"` or `"(?<=\\G.{3})"`

```
String s = "1234567890abcdef";
int n = 3;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.split("(?<=\\G.{"+n+"})")));

//output: [123, 456, 789, 0ab, cde, f]
```

How to modify the above regex to split at every **2nd** and **3rd** char alternately?

A naive chaining like `"(?<=\\G.{2})(?<=\\G.{3})"` did not work.

Comment: Do you have to use regex? This would be much easier if you didn't - just write a simple loop that takes off 2 characters, then 3, then 2 and so on. If you must do regex though, simply take off 5, then know that each group of 5 can be split into a 2 and a 3.

Comment: Let me know if you want a pseudo code example of what that would look like.

Comment: @davidalayachew I am also trying with loops and substring method, but still struggling with arrayIndexOutOfBound because of last value can be shorter than 2. Would love to see your approach even if it is a pseudo code.

Comment: Looks like there are already some very useful solutions down below - I would encourage you to pick one of those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with `split()`, because every match should be aware of the pattern previously matched.

If you don't want to manually iterate over the string's characters, you can use something like this:

```java
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.{0,2})(.{0,3})").matcher("1234567890abcdef");
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (!m.group(i).isEmpty()) {
      list.add(m.group(i));
    }
  }
}
System.out.println(list);  // prints [12, 345, 67, 890, ab, cde, f]
```

Comment: Nice solution! I would suggest  to put the `list.add(m.group(i));` inside a `{}` scope to make it more readable.

Comment: That is perfect and exactly what i need and and is expandable if my pattern is, for example, `XX XXX XXXXX`.

Comment: Yes, in that case remember to replace `i <= 2` with `i <= 3` (or use `m.groupCount()`).

Comment: In the for loop it is a little better to write:
for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)

Comment: @TalGlik That is exactly what I said in the last comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

O(n) solution by iterating over the characters:

```
private static List<String> splitByPattern(String str, List<Integer> pattern) {
    int currentPatternIndex = 0;
    int iterationsTillNextSplit = pattern.get(currentPatternIndex);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();

    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (iterationsTillNextSplit == 0) { // Time to split
            strs.add(stringBuilder.toString());
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            iterationsTillNextSplit = pattern.get(++currentPatternIndex % pattern.size());
        }

        stringBuilder.append(c);
        iterationsTillNextSplit--;
    }

    strs.add(stringBuilder.toString());

    return strs;
}
```

Usage:

```
System.out.println(splitByPattern("1234567890abcdef", Arrays.asList(2, 3)));
```

Output:

```
[12, 345, 67, 890, ab, cde, f]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simple solution which doesn't make use of regular expressions:

```java
String s = "1234567890abcdef";
int strLen = s.length();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int lastIndex = 0; lastIndex < strLen;) {
    int numChars = list.size() % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 3; // this alternates substrings of length 2 and 3
    if (strLen - lastIndex < numChars)
        list.add(s.substring(lastIndex));
    else
        list.add(s.substring(lastIndex, lastIndex+numChars));
    lastIndex += numChars;
}
System.out.println(list);  // prints [12, 345, 67, 890, ab, cde, f]
```

Comment: Learned a few things today, thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

There is a somewhat hacky way to `split()` using regex, but as @horcrux mentioned:

> every match should be aware of the pattern previously matched

You would have to:

a) insert an anchor to make further backreferences by adding a "unlikely" character or string (e.g. line-break) into every i + j position first:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(.{5})", "$1\n");
```

So that your string transforms to `12345\n67890\nabcde\nf`

b) Now you can split by looking around

```
String[] result = s.split("(?<=\\G.{2})(?=.{3}\n)|\n");
```

where you look for a zero-length match having `i` characters on the left `(?<=\G.{2})` and followed by `j` characters ending with your "special" pattern **OR** just match your "special" pattern if not found.

This allows alternating split either at a position `i` or at the match of "special" pattern.

[image: using hash # as special pattern]

Complete one-liner (for educational purposes only):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s.replaceAll("(.{"+(i+j)+"})", "$1#").split("(?<=\\G.{"+i+"})(?=.{"+j+"}#)|#")));
```

Comment: If the chosen strategy is "split after the fifth character and then split after the second character", I would instead opt for a functional solution:  `System.out.println(Arrays.stream(s.split("(?<=\\G.{"+(i+j)+"})")).map(t -> t.split("(?<=^.{"+i+"})")).flatMap(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()));`